# what is the Input impedance of transmission line, when source frequency contains two frequency components?

Tags: transmission-line, power-engineering, input-impedance

what is the Input impedance of transmission line, when source frequency contains two frequency components?

I know the expression of input impedance of a TL, but it assumes that only a single frequency component is present in the source. What if source is providing power having two frequency components?

---

[image: attached is the figure]
S1 and S2 are sources, l1,l2 are self inductance of coil and M is the mutual inductance. Zin1 and Zin2 are the input inpedance of TL.

S1 and S2 have diffrent frequency.

Comment: This is just the bacis knowledge of TL. My question is a bit different.

Comment: What are L1 and L2?

Comment: L1 and L2 are unmatched resistive loads.

Answer (score 3):

If your system is linear, you can analyze the behavior at each frequency seperately. You don't need to define a single input impedance that applies to both frequencies. You analyze the response to stimulus at \$f_1\$ using the input impedance at \$f_1\$, and you analyze the response to stimulus at \$f_2\$ using the input impedance at \$f_2\$.

Then you use the linearity of the system so that the response \$y\$ to the combined stimulus \$x_1+x_2\$ is just \$y(x_1+x_2) = y(x_1) + y(x_2)\$

Comment: thank-you for your prompt response, but my problem is that i can not analyze it using a single frequency at a time. My circuit contains a mutual inductance element before the TL start, and a secondary circuit is inducing voltage at different frequency in my primary circuit. ^ So, it has to analyzed in presence of both frequencies. because if i turn off one source there will be no mutual coupling between the two networks.

Comment: A mutual inductance is still linear, and you can still use superposition to analyze the circuit.

Comment: If the circuit is nonlinear, then you can't really talk about it having an "input impedance" in the conventional sense to begin with.

Comment: What method can be used to analyze the circuit if it is non-linear.

Comment: Then you need to share your circuit so we can understand what kind of nonlinear circuit it is.

Comment: Kindly check the post again, i have added  an image.

Comment: Nothing in your diagram shows any nonlinearity. You can analyzer your circuit using superposition.

Comment: but if i apply superposition, i can not take into account the effect of mutual coupling between the two circuits.

Comment: @user43765, yes you can. When you solve with just S1 active, you will find an induced current in the right loop. When you solve with just S2 active, you will find an induced current in the left loop. Add the currents from the two solutions together and you have the total current when both sources are active.